# Split a big album audio file into separate songs audio files automatically

Tags: music

I have an audio file which contains many songs in it. I want to split it into many audio files with separate songs automatically (probably by AI). Is there something can do that?

Comment: Which file format?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: I've only tried Google with "AI split songs" keywords. I have no idea what should try next.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way I could think to logically do this is if you can detect a pause between the songs that matches a certain length threshold, which if it is a recording of analog album would likely be impossible as there would still be noise.

This means you'd have to use a wave file reading library to do this.

That's the programmatic answer I'm not sure about ai.